# helm rollout restart with changes in configmap.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

Helm has recently added support for [automatically-roll-deployments](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments) but we need to set a configmap.yaml file where it looks for changes.

In my usecase we have a single yaml file `deploy-template.yaml` with structure -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}

{...}
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
{...}
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
{...}
```

Is there a way to keep track of the `ConfigMap` from the `Deployment` above in the same file?

Last resort would be to separate `ConfigMap` out into a new file.

Comment: That's not specifically tied to a ConfigMap object; it just renders the ConfigMap data and calculates a hash of it.  Whatever inputs you want to put into the `sha256sum` will have the same effect even if it's not the actual ConfigMap data _per se_.

Comment: Can you help with the input we have to pass to checksum annotation? From the example I gave above we're passing configmap.yaml file as input @DavidMaze