# yaml reference "___" seperated kubernetes object

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a file like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}

{...}
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
{...}
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
{...}
```

This has 3 objects separated by `---`. I want to reference `ConfigMap` object inside `Deployment` to use with `checksum` annotation. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Is this the same as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72953989/helm-rollout-restart-with-changes-in-configmap-yaml)?

Comment: @DavidMaze, Yes I was looking for a way to give input from the same file. (Commented there in other ticket)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a template system like [this one](https://github.com/cbroglie/mustache), which will process your YAMLs and generate the desired manifests for your resources.

I suspect you will have to declare your `ConfigMap` as a variable that can be substituted in your `deployment.yaml` by the template system.

Alternatively, you can look at the `kustomize` system which also provides templatized generation of manifests. An example on how to deal with annotations with `kustomize` can be found [here](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/guides/config_management/labels_annotations/).